# Why does the 'Free/Busy' time for Google Calendar API come back 'Undefined'?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-api

I'm new to and learning both Javascript and Google Script, and I'm trying to write a script that checks if a calendar is busy at a certain time. According to https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/freebusy/query, this should be returned in the format:

```
{
  "kind": "calendar#freeBusy",
  "timeMin": datetime,
  "timeMax": datetime,
  "calendars": {
    "busy": [{"start": datetime,"end": datetime}]
  }
}
```

However, I'm using the following code (Simplified to reproduce the issue):

```
function checkResource() {
 var calendarId = [The Calendars ID removed for privacy];
 var check = {
    items: [{id: calendarId, busy: 'Active'}],
    timeMax: "2014-09-09T21:00:31-00:00",
    timeMin: "2014-09-09T17:00:31-00:00"
 };  

 var response = Calendar.Freebusy.query(check);

 Logger.log('Response: '+ response);
 Logger.log('Response Calendars: '+ response.calendars.calendarId);

 for (var property in response){
    Logger.log('Property: '+ property);
    Logger.log('Property Value: '+ response[property]);
 }

 for (var calendarValue in response){
   Logger.log('Calendar Value: '+ response.calendars.calendarValue);
 };
}
```

Which logs for me all of the calendar properties, but for some reason won't return anything apart from '[object Object]' or 'undefined' when I try to get into the nested 'busy' object.[image: Screenshot of logging output]

The calendar is intentionally busy during this time (there's an event on at 2014-09-09T18:00:00Z which lasts for an hour), and you can see this when I log the entire function (Logger.log('Response: '+ response); shows the calendar ID, 'busy' and the start and end time), so I've clearly gone wrong with my code.

Any assistance would be great.

Comment: thanks for revealing this feature I didn't know :-)  very interesting actually !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taking a "deep" look in the logger I came up to this code that seems to return what you wanted :

```
function checkResource() {
  var calendarId = ["_________________o9mvpo5r5cvb5nb4cg@group.calendar.google.com"];
  var check = {
 items: [{id: calendarId, busy: 'Active'}],
 timeMax: "2014-09-09T21:00:31-00:00",
 timeMin: "2014-09-09T17:00:31-00:00"
};  

  var response = Calendar.Freebusy.query(check);
  Logger.log(response.kind)
  Logger.log('Time MIN = '+response.timeMin)
  Logger.log('Time MAX = '+response.timeMax)
  Logger.log('busy start = '+response.calendars[calendarId].busy[0].start)
  Logger.log('busy end = '+response.calendars[calendarId].busy[0].end)
}
```

Result log :

```
[14-09-10 15:50:51:724 CEST] calendar#freeBusy
[14-09-10 15:50:51:724 CEST] Time MIN = 2014-09-09T17:00:31.000Z
[14-09-10 15:50:51:724 CEST] Time MAX = 2014-09-09T21:00:31.000Z
[14-09-10 15:50:51:725 CEST] busy start = 2014-09-09T17:00:31Z
[14-09-10 15:50:51:725 CEST] busy end = 2014-09-09T18:00:00Z
```

Log from the basic values :

```
[14-09-10 15:47:37:676 CEST] Response: {"kind":"calendar#freeBusy","timeMin":"2014-09-09T17:00:31.000Z","calendars":{"_____________9mvpo5r5cvb5nb4cg@group.calendar.google.com":{"busy":[{"start":"2014-09-09T17:00:31Z","end":"2014-09-09T18:00:00Z"}]}},"timeMax":"2014-09-09T21:00:31.000Z"}
```

Full script derived from yours :

```
function checkResource() {
  var calendarId = ["________________vb5nb4cg@group.calendar.google.com"];
  var check = {
 items: [{id: calendarId, busy: 'Active'}],
 timeMax: "2014-09-09T21:00:31-00:00",
 timeMin: "2014-09-09T17:00:31-00:00"
};  

  var response = Calendar.Freebusy.query(check);
  Logger.log(response.kind)
  Logger.log('Time MIN = '+response.timeMin)
  Logger.log('Time MAX = '+response.timeMax)
  Logger.log('busy start = '+response.calendars[calendarId].busy[0].start)
  Logger.log('busy end = '+response.calendars[calendarId].busy[0].end)

  Logger.log('Response: '+ response);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this gave me what I needed to figure it out! For some reason it throws 'Start is undefined' when no event exists, and only works when an event does exist. Not sure why it doesn't just return a blank value.... I've marked your advice as 'Accepted'.