# How can I check the availability of an email id in google calender to be shown in google form

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api, google-forms

I am quite new to google app scripting and looking for best suggestions and lookouts,
I have made a form that creates the meeting event in gogole app script,  and I need to add the possibility of checking the availability of any email id I am inviting to the meeting.

The code for creating a meeting invite.

```
function CreateEvent_( NamedValues )
{
 var calendar = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar();  
var cEvent1 = calendar.createEvent(NamedValues.Subject_Title, new Date(NamedValues.Start_date_time_1), new Date(NamedValues.End_date_time_1), {description: NamedValues.Description_Competency_1+NamedValues.Interview_1_Type, location: NamedValues.Location_1[0], guests: guestList1, sendInvites: true}); 
}

function OnFormSubmit(e) 
{ 
  Logger.log(e.namedValues);
  CreateEvent_(e.namedValues );    
}

function updateSheet()
{
  //code to update sheet

}
```

How can I include a section where we can check the availablity of any email id we are including in the meeting

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I never used it but if I read the documentation on [Advanced Calendar Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/calendar) and particularly the [Freebusy page](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/freebusy/query#try-it) it seems that you can get the availability of a group or a single user.

If you come to a working solution I would be happy to see it.

Edit:   see also this post with a sample code [Why does the 'Free/Busy' time for Google Calendar API come back 'Undefined'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25734575/why-does-the-free-busy-time-for-google-calendar-api-come-back-undefined)